# Threadsafety of Ruby variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency

This is a very basic concurrency question.

In Ruby, is it safe to assume that any state stored in a local variable is threadsafe?

Specifically, I'm thinking of a request in a Rails app. If I were to store state on the User class, I think that would be asking for concurrency trouble. But if I instantiate a user (eg, the Devise `current_user` method during a request, assuming that method doesn't use a global for its own state under the hood), and I never assign that user to a global variable or constant, I should be able to modify state on that instance with no concerns about thread safety, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should have specified a Ruby implementation; I know that they vary in their support of multithreading...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are right, inside a single request you can safely use any local variables unless you are spawning any threads yourself.

Also if you use server like Unicorn that uses workers (separate process) for processing requests you are "threadsafe" as each process lives in its own memory space and only one request is being processed at a time.

Problems may occur if you have a threaded server like Puma that can process multiple requests in parallel inside a single Ruby process. This is where race conditions may start and if you have a code like:

```
class User
  delf.self.current_user
    @@current_user
  end
end

User.current_user.destroy
```

The `@@current_user` variable may get changed by parallel process and you can accidentally destroy wrong user.

Comment: Even the example you give would be safe in a multi-process (as opposed to multi-threaded) model, correct?